# How to autofit table cells in Birt report to fit content when generating pdf

Tags: pdf, birt

I have a BIRT Report using a table with variable amounts of data. If there is too much data then when I generate a pdf the table doesn't resize to fit everything. It renders fine using the HTML output but with a pdf a lot of my information is getting cut off.

How can I fix my report so no matter how much data is in the table it'll resize to fit when I generate the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

In your InterfaceIPDFRender, set your [PAGE_OVERFLOW](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc.isv%2Fengine%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fbirt%2Freport%2Fengine%2Fapi%2FIPDFRenderOption.html) = FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE and that should do it

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

In the report properties, use Layout Preference: Fixed Layout.

When running the report as PDF:

```
IRenderOption options = new RenderOption();
PDFRenderOption pdfOptions = new PDFRenderOption(options);
pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, IPDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_TO_MULTIPLE_PAGES);
pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_TEXT_WRAPPING, true);
pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_HYPHENATION, true);
runAndRenderTask.setRenderOption(options);
runAndRenderTask.run();
```