# canShrink property on LabelHandle is not working with PDF and EXCEL Report using BIRT

Tags: java, birt

I am working with BIRT(4.6) and Eclipse mars2(4.5).
I am creating a report using EngineConfig object and creating the report in HTML, PDF and EXCEL formats.

The number of the tables and data inside the table I am filling dynamically.

I am creating the CellHandle for each column in my report and adding the LabelHandle inside it. I was setting the  width of a LabelHandle based on the size of the String that I am going to set it and All three reports(PDF, HTML and EXCEL) were displaying properly. But setting the LabelHandle width based string size, is not a good practice and sometimes data is missing in the reports.
So Tried with 'canShrink' property on LabelHandle as shown below.

labelHandleObj.setProperty("canShrink", "True");

The above statement automatically adjust LableHandle width based on the String size and this avoids me to set the LableHandle size manually based string size.

With the canShrink property my HTML report is generating properly with no data loss and No extract space/padding in cell. This is the way I want the report.

But when it comes to PDF and EXCEL, Tables are not displaying properly and all columns are shirked and data is not displaying properly. You can see the PDF Report by clicking the below link.

[PDF Report after setting the canShrink property on LableHandle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCkZo.png)

Can any one kindly suggest me, how to get the data properly in PDF and Excel Report. But I want to use the CanShrink property, because it is creating the proper HTML report.I tried with both True and False value for CanShrink but no use with PDF and EXCEL.

Is there any way to get the three reports properly without using CanShrink.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When something like this happens you should try copy your table and insert it under original table, then hide original table from PDF using the `visibility` tab, then hide the copy from everything but PDF. I've done this a lot of times and it really solves the problem, but major disadvantage of this is that if you want to change something you have to do in two tables. Example report:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Klimiuk.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Klimiuk.                                                                                                          Means you are suggesting  to modify the .rptDesign file manually?

Comment: according to my requirement...user will select the data file for which he/she wants to generates the report and select the option for report file format(HTML/PDF/EXCEL which is provided by me) and generates report.So its not possible to edit the .rptdesign file backgroup at runtime.

Comment: You have to edit the .rptdesign file in BIRT. And just use visibility tab to hide tables. And if user selects pdf, the one table will be visible in PDF and another in HTML, so it doesn't require additional actions from user.

Comment: I think you miss understood my requirement. I am not creating data source and data set,  as I mentioned above everything even tables also I am creating programmatically. I want full report in HTML, PDF and EXCEL format, not like one table in one format.

Comment: I set the table width to 100% table.setWidth("100%"); now I am able to see the data in PDF and EXCEL reports. But still some data got cut in PDF and EXCEL due to very lengthy column heading.Can anybody have a solution how to shrink/expand the columns based on the column heading size.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to adjust report design parameters or just table properties so I that the table would shrink/expand based on size/length of column heading.

Comment: My issue is resolved by adding the below properties to PDFRenderOption as shown below

Comment: PDFRenderOption pdfRenderOption = new PDFRenderOption();
   pdfRenderOption.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, IPDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_TO_MULTIPLE_PAGES);
   pdfRenderOption.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_TEXT_WRAPPING, true);
   pdfRenderOption.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_HYPHENATION, true);
   task.setRenderOption(pdfRenderOption);

Comment: Now data inside the Label is skipping to multiple lines and able to see the full data in the column label. You can also refer below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481683/how-to-autofit-table-cells-in-birt-report-to-fit-content-when-generating-pdf?rq=1